# Vim ruby autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, autocomplete, omnicomplete

I give up. This

```
 51   if !exists('g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns')
 52        let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns = {}
 53   endif
 54
 55   if !exists('g:neocomplcache_omni_functions')
 56        let g:neocomplcache_omni_functions = {}
 57   endif
 58   let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns['ruby'] = '[^. \t]\.\w*'
 59   let g:neocomplcache_omni_functions['ruby'] = 'rubycomplete#Complete'
 60   autocmd FileType ruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
```

is a part of my .gvimrc file.

The problem is that I can't setup omni autocompletion for ruby. If I type C-x C-y it works, but not while I'm writing code. It works fine for php, html, css etc

Comment: Note: Even if you only use GVIM, put only GUI-related stuff in `.gvimrc`; everything else should be in `.vimrc`. Doesn't matter for your problem, though :-)

Answer (score 7):

although I don't use neocomplcache I'm fairly satisfied with [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby), including code-completion.
Just having Vim compiled with ruby support, added to .vimrc

```
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1 
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
autocmd FileType ruby,eruby let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

As highly dynamic nature of Ruby, the code completion will be always limited to some degree, but above really helps with completion of standard classes and methods, even most of your own.